# Will loss of contact with the ground remove friction forces?

Tags: forces, friction

If we suppose that one object is losing contact from the floor, let's say the trajectory of this object is a semisphere, then in this instantaneous time just before the contact is loss will make the friction forces due to the floor disappear?

Comment: Obviously, as the moving object loses contact with the floor, its friction with the floor will go to zero. Is this what you're asking, or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, I was asking exactly what you answered. I just asked to make sure of one assumption that I've made in an exercise, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic approximation for the force of friction is
$$F_f = \mu F_N$$
While the frictional force in reality is more complicated, it's a pretty good approximation for many everyday circumstances.

Therefore, in the instant when the object is leaving the surface (and afterwards), $F_N = 0$, by the above equation, $F_f = 0$.